# Including a custom converter from a different assembly

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying implement a custom converter from a different assembly but it seems to be getting ignored. I have beat this to death and can't see my error so maybe some XAML ninja could help out. Here is the relevant code...

```
 xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Shared.Converters;assembly=Shared"
```

And the resource dictionary...

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Shared;component/Styles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <converters:SaveStatusConverter x:Key="saveStateConverter" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is the entire converter itself.

namespace Shared.Converters
{
  public class SaveStatusConverter : IValueConverter
  {

```
public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{

  bool? buttonState = (bool?)value;
  Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/Shared;component/Styles.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
  ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
  if(buttonState == true)
    return resourceDictionary["GreenDot"] as Style;
  if (buttonState == false)
    return resourceDictionary["RedDot"] as Style;
  return resourceDictionary["GreyDot"] as Style;

}

public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

}
}

And here is my implementation...

```
<ContentControl Style="{Binding Path=SaveState, Converter={StaticResource saveStateConverter}}"/>
```

I know the styles work... that isn't an issue, I think the converter is fine too, it must have something to do with the way I am trying to call it although I can't see the issue...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Err, grumble grumble... I had a typo in the name of my default state "gray" not "grey" - Anyway - this is not a too bad example of how to do this. :)